# I have to set the character count using ngclass in Angular

Tags: angular

app.component.html:

```
      <div class="col-md-7 p-0 pr-2 pb-2 pt-2 "
          <span class="pb-2 pt-2">{{item.name}}</span>
      </div>
```

if item.name character was more than 300 then the height of that should be 100px. else 50px.

Comment: Maybe https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  <div class="col-md-7 p-0 pr-2 pb-2 pt-2 ">
              <span class="pb-2 pt-2" [style.height]='item.name.length > 300 ? "100px" : "50px"'>{{item.name}}</span>
          </div>
```